# Increase time for FIN after the last packet (jetty server, centos os)

Tags: java, android, centos, jetty, tcpdump

I have built a Restesy service with Jetty in CentOS, there's no problem with Window Phone or IOS client, but with Android client, timeout occur with high rate.
I track connection by tcpdump and see that packets when timeout occur or not is similar, e.g: 
TIMEOUT

```
10:24:38.359095 IP 116.101.38.222.47360 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [S], seq 888244766, win 14600, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 4903276 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:24:38.359138 IP 123.30.210.5.8890 > 116.101.38.222.47360: Flags [S.], seq 2238335766, ack 888244767, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2336383696 ecr 4903276,nop,wscale 9], length 0
10:24:38.362449 IP 116.101.38.222.47360 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [.], ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 4903278 ecr 2336383696], length 0
10:24:38.392668 IP 116.101.38.222.47360 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [P.], seq 1:837, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 4903280 ecr 2336383696], length 836
10:24:38.392697 IP 123.30.210.5.8890 > 116.101.38.222.47360: Flags [.], ack 837, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 2336383729 ecr 4903280], length 0
10:24:38.617932 IP 123.30.210.5.8890 > 116.101.38.222.47360: Flags [P.], seq 1:365, ack 837, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 2336383955 ecr 4903280], length 364
10:24:38.618078 IP 123.30.210.5.8890 > 116.101.38.222.47360: Flags [P.], seq 365:372, ack 837, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 2336383955 ecr 4903280], length 7
10:24:38.621261 IP 116.101.38.222.47360 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [.], ack 365, win 123, options [nop,nop,TS val 4903303 ecr 2336383955], length 0
10:24:38.621894 IP 116.101.38.222.47360 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [.], ack 372, win 123, options [nop,nop,TS val 4903303 ecr 2336383955], length 0
10:25:08.619071 IP 123.30.210.5.8890 > 116.101.38.222.47360: Flags [F.], seq 372, ack 837, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 2336413956 ecr 4903303], length 0
10:25:08.692600 IP 116.101.38.222.47360 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [.], ack 373, win 123, options [nop,nop,TS val 4906311 ecr 2336413956], length 0
```

NORMAL

```
10:27:36.913571 IP 116.101.38.222.47371 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [S], seq 2720593029, win 14600, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 4910920 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:27:36.913599 IP 123.30.210.5.8890 > 116.101.38.222.47371: Flags [S.], seq 4293963922, ack 2720593030, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2336562250 ecr 4910920,nop,wscale 9], length 0
10:27:36.916232 IP 116.101.38.222.47371 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [.], ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 4910920 ecr 2336562250], length 0
10:27:36.929731 IP 116.101.38.222.47371 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [P.], seq 1:837, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 4910922 ecr 2336562250], length 836
10:27:36.929750 IP 123.30.210.5.8890 > 116.101.38.222.47371: Flags [.], ack 837, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 2336562266 ecr 4910922], length 0
10:27:36.933454 IP 123.30.210.5.8890 > 116.101.38.222.47371: Flags [P.], seq 1:365, ack 837, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 2336562270 ecr 4910922], length 364
10:27:36.933532 IP 123.30.210.5.8890 > 116.101.38.222.47371: Flags [P.], seq 365:372, ack 837, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 2336562270 ecr 4910922], length 7
10:27:36.936567 IP 116.101.38.222.47371 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [.], ack 365, win 123, options [nop,nop,TS val 4910922 ecr 2336562270], length 0
10:27:36.936963 IP 116.101.38.222.47371 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [.], ack 372, win 123, options [nop,nop,TS val 4910922 ecr 2336562270], length 0
10:28:06.933824 IP 123.30.210.5.8890 > 116.101.38.222.47371: Flags [F.], seq 372, ack 837, win 32, options [nop,nop,TS val 2336592270 ecr 4910922], length 0
10:28:07.029333 IP 116.101.38.222.47371 > 123.30.210.5.8890: Flags [.], ack 373, win 123, options [nop,nop,TS val 4913932 ecr 2336592270], length 0
```

I can not understand my problem, but I see that , server send FIN packet after the last ACk packet 30s, so I want to increase this time to 60s or greater. If you known how to increase this time, or you known my problem, please help me.
Thank you very much,
Cong

Comment: What version of Jetty? What version of Android? Is SSL involved?

Comment: Jetty 9.2.2, almost all version of Android, no SSL :(